# Liferay CE 7.2.1 GA2 - Resolve custom modules dependancies after upgrade

Tags: maven, dependencies, liferay, liferay-7

I have complete an upgrade of my Liferay from version CE 7.1.0 GA1 to Liferay CE 7.2.1 GA2.

I'm now stuck on my custom module dependancies to upgrade.

For example :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.liferay.portal.kernel</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

In the portal-kernel.jar available in my bundle, i found the version 4.35.4 but it can't be imported via maven.

Is there a solution to have all version modules compatible with my new liferay versions ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could also work :

```
<properties>
   <liferay.bom.version>7.2.1-1</liferay.bom.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
                    <artifactId>release.portal.bom</artifactId>
                    <version>${liferay.bom.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
                    <artifactId>release.portal.bom.compile.only</artifactId>
                    <version>${liferay.bom.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
                    <artifactId>release.portal.bom.third.party</artifactId>
                    <version>${liferay.bom.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: always try to use maven bom model provided by liferay as @DyM mentioned. this will avoid all the dependency conflict or missing from Liferay repository for even other modules as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sobstitute the core dependencies list with an unique release.portal.api import.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay.portal/release.portal.api/7.2.1-ga2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
    <artifactId>release.portal.api</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.1-ga2</version>
</dependency>
```